# How do I actually make Chrome the default browser?

Tags: windows-8

Chrome [says its my default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p1LU.png) but every time I click a link in an external program it opens in Firefox. How can I change my default browser?

Note that [Firefox *also* thinks its the default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYwCk.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a setting in Windows 8 for this. Open your start screen and search for "Choose a default web browser".

[image: Windows 8 default apps]